# Sorting HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

So, I was following this guide on W3C on how to sort my table:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp

The second example works for me as I have two (of four) columns that I want to be able to sort by, however, the slight difference is my columns are numeric, not text, so the sort performs, but, doesn't actually sort.

I tried adding the numerical code in the example below in and it doesn't do anything, clicking the header has become like there's no code at all:

```
<script>
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable2");
  switching = true;
  // Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc";
  /* Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done: */
  while (switching) {
    // Start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    /* Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers): */
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      // Start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /* Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next: */
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /* Check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc: */
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (Number(x.innerHTML) > Number(y.innerHTML)) {
          // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (Number(x.innerHTML) < Number(y.innerHTML)) {
          // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done: */
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      // Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount ++;
    } else {
      /* If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again. */
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I also tried just the code out of the numerical example on one column and it does nothing too:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sort_table_number

So I'm obviously missing something blindingly obvious, but, as I'm not a programmer I thought I could just tinker with the bits I did above and it'd be sorted = \

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you set any breakpoints in your code via the browser dev tools and stepped into the code? Is the console window displaying any exception (errors) when you run your code?

Comment: the variable `n` in `rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n]`  is supposed to be the column index. What value is it given in the call to `sortTable` ? Is it the value of an existing index?

Comment: Have you bound an event on the cells of your first row to this function ? In another hand, this way to do is really poor in performance ! For instance, a desc sort on a previously asc sorted table will make an amazing number of dom moves, instead of just reverse the table.

Comment: use bootstrap tables